# Why is data generated from a randomly constructed Markov chain not compressible?

Tags: data-compression, markov-chains

For a project I'm working on, I need to generate some data to test the Gzip compressor, and I wrote [my own](https://github.com/dannyniu/NestedMarkovChain/blob/eac79f5367fbade7060e082bfb7de611bece832b/src/NestedMarkovChain.py) implementation of Markov chain for it, and it's a 2-level nested one.

But when I generate data using my script and feed it to Gzip, it always - without exception - expands the data, as if there's no redundancy in it.

What could be causing this? How can I modify my Markov chain so that it generates compressible data?

Answer (score 1):

In the factory function that generates MC definition, each state has the probability of transitioning to other states that're uniformly random, I guess that this is the biggest problem.

Suggestion for improvement: Make the probability more sparse and skewed for each state for starters.

(I've made a [new commit](https://github.com/dannyniu/NestedMarkovChain/blob/a362ce178ae2d641f9bd9befe078683828c58155/src/NestedMarkovChain.py))

Comment: I confirm this did work. Although it occasionally generates un-compressible data, it's perfect for testing edge cases.